# How to make notification to group users with read/unread flag?

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, database-design, notifications

I am making a notification system so that when users in a group perform an action, it will notify all the other users in the group. I want the notification to be marked "read" or "unread" for each user of the group. With that, I can easily retreive any unread notification for a user and display it. I am think about creating a notification table that have the following fields.

```
+----------------------+
| notification         |
+----------------------+
| id                   |
| userid               |
| content              |
| status (read/unread) |
| time                 |
+----------------------+
```

My question is:

1. Whether it is the correct way of making the system? As it means that when there is 1,000 users in a group, then I have to insert 1,000 rows to the table. If not, what is the better way of doing this?
2. If it is the way to do this, how can I write the php/mysql codes to do the looping of inserting the rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A better way of doing that would be to separate the notification from the user, by doing the following:

```
Table Notification
------------------
not_id
time content

Table User
----------
u_id

Table NotificationStatus
------------------------
id
u_id
not_id
bool read
```

That way you have to save each notification only one, what makes it easier to modify/edit notifications

Comment: Hai i'm new at this forum please don't vote down ya, just want to know your logic  how can i count notification which is not read by user ?

i mean when user a loggin and he diddn't read the notification ?
let say has 3 notification, and after read one notication how can i reduction the notification, i hope you understand cause english is not my native langunge,

Comment: @Freddy you'd display only the notifications that are not found to be read by the user: `SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE not_id NOT IN ( SELECT not_id FROM NotificationStatus WHERE read)`; that should give you the notifications that were not read at all, addiotionally the user id would need to be put in that request.

Comment: Thanks for your help, by the way is it allowed to comment another answer in old post in this forum, Thanks

Comment: @FreddySidauruk generally, if you have a concrete problen you need help with, you could simply create a question. The comment section is usually not for personal support. But be sure to check out the [Answer section of that page](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

yes..u can do it in this manner..
example: suppose any user "PQP" (user_id=1) is adding a photo then u have to write ur notification query on success of photo adding query (u need to write write query for notification on code wherever u want that point as notification) so your notification table will got new entry as

```
id = 1                
userid =1           
content = "Photo Added By User PQP"            
status = Unread
time = currenttime
```

so by this case whenever someone uploads a photo then notification table will got entry in it..

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following data structure:

```
Table: Events
----------------
event_id
user_id (foreign key to users table)
action_id (foreign key to actions table)
time_stamp

Table: Log
----------------
user_id (foreign key to users table)
event_id (foreign key to events table)
time_stamp
```

The logic should be that all events are considered unread by user X unless Log table contains the event_id for that user

Actions table may have many types of actions.

You will be able to count and notify all users how many other users have "recieved" the action by querying the log. etc'...

Comment: This is nice.. But with the old method, I can remove read notifications from time to time. With this way, it seems that it's not that possible, and the table will just accumulate...